# Php get data from Angular post

Tags: php, angularjs

How can php to get the values from the Angular post request?

**php**

```
$data = $_GET['params'] or $_REQUEST['params']; 
echo $data;
```

**Angular**

```
  var params = {
            "key":"value"
        }

         $http.get('php-page.php', {params:params})
            .then(function(response){
                var mydata = response.data; 
                return $scope.myresponse = mydata;           
        });
```

Comment: All Post request can be get in PHP via `$_POST['your_item']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your php file use the following code to get the post values from the angular post values.

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
```

Example:

```
$userName   = isset($objData->userName) ? $objData->userName : '';
```

Comment: file_get_contents is getting the contents from the page and not the request